# Magento Developer Client Restrictions

Tags: magento, client, restrictions

Whan I attempt to use Developer Client Restrictions, should I use my LAN IP address or my public IP address? I am accessing the site remotely. I assume it\’s the public IP, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

**The Developer Client Restrictions setting *does not* restrict access to the site.** Rather, that setting is evaluated in several different contexts to determine whether certain developer-related behaviors such as logging and template path hints should display. (It's sometimes buggy, e.g. breadcrumb block behavior with FPC & that setting turned on).

You will need to use the address which will be provided to the application via `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (your public IP in this case).

Comment: Its use is unfortunately not obvious. Magento, Inc. is [drastically overhauling the admin](http://blog.mageupdate.com/2013/02/magento-2-admin-theme-sneak-peek.html) to reduce this confusion in Magento 2.